CS50x 2024 - tideman_test.c not compiling
check50 fails to compile for tideman.c (full error here)
tideman.c itself compiles fine (both locally with make and in check50) but tideman_test.c doesn't:
running clang tideman.c -o tideman -std=c11 -ggdb -lm -lcs50...
running clang tideman_test.c -o tideman_test -std=c11 -ggdb -lm -lcs50...
tideman_test.c:220:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'main_id'
while (main_id < left_half_size + right_half_size)
^
tideman_test.c:235:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'main_id'
tmp_pairs[main_id] = left_half[left_id];
^
tideman_test.c:239:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'main_id'
main_id += 1;
^
tideman_test.c:240:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'main_id'
tmp_pairs[main_id] = right_half[right_id];
^
tideman_test.c:246:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'main_id'
tmp_pairs[main_id] = right_half[right_id];
^
tideman_test.c:249:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'main_id'
main_id += 1;
^
6 errors generated.

I've gone through a bunch of similar posts on Reddit and SOF where the usual causes for this are changing the pre-declared prototypes or some code in main but all I can see when comparing the first and latest versions of my tideman.c are:

code in place of the //TODO placeholders
new functions (and associated prototypes)

To be clear, the error is with tideman_test.c not compiling but that file is on CS50's side only, I have no such file. The code erroring though does come from tideman.c
Full tideman.c:
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
} pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);
bool merge_sort_pairs(pair *pairs, int pairs_size);
int get_pair_score(pair pair);
bool is_adding_pair_creating_a_loop(pair pair_to_add);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        // Candidate found
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i]) == 0)
        {
            ranks[rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count - 1; i++)
    {
        int stronger_candidate_id = ranks[i];
        // Then count
        for (int j = i + 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            int lesser_candidate_id = ranks[j];
            preferences[stronger_candidate_id][lesser_candidate_id] += 1;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    // Scan the array up to size/2 (rounded up)
    // Unnecessary: int array_half_size = ceil(candidate_count / 2.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            // i preferred over j
            if (preferences[i][j] > preferences[j][i])
            {
                pair new_pair;
                new_pair.winner = i;
                new_pair.loser = j;
                pairs[pair_count] = new_pair;
                pair_count += 1;
            }
            // j preferred over i
            else if (preferences[i][j] < preferences[j][i])
            {
                pair new_pair;
                new_pair.winner = j;
                new_pair.loser = i;
                pairs[pair_count] = new_pair;
                pair_count += 1;
            }
            // else do nothing
        }
    }
    return;
}

int get_pair_score(pair pair)
{
    return preferences[pair.winner][pair.loser];
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    merge_sort_pairs(pairs, pair_count);
    return;
}

bool merge_sort_pairs(pair *pairs_to_sort, int pairs_to_sort_size)
{
    if (pairs_to_sort_size == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        int left_half_size = pairs_to_sort_size / 2;
        int right_half_size;
        if (pairs_to_sort_size % 2 == 0)
        {
            right_half_size = pairs_to_sort_size / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            right_half_size = pairs_to_sort_size / 2 + 1;
        }
        // 1. Sort left half
        pair left_half[left_half_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < left_half_size; i++)
        {
            left_half[i] = pairs_to_sort[i];
        }
        merge_sort_pairs(left_half, left_half_size);

        // 2. Sort right half
        pair right_half[right_half_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < right_half_size; i++)
        {
            right_half[i] = pairs_to_sort[left_half_size + i];
        }
        merge_sort_pairs(right_half, right_half_size);

        // 3. Merge
        pair tmp_pairs[left_half_size + right_half_size];
        int left_id = 0;
        int right_id = 0;
        int main_id = 0;
        int left_pair_score = get_pair_score(left_half[left_id]);
        int right_pair_score = get_pair_score(right_half[right_id]);
        while (main_id < left_half_size + right_half_size)
        {
            // Don't overflow
            if (left_id < left_half_size)
            {
                left_pair_score = get_pair_score(left_half[left_id]);
            }
            if (right_id < right_half_size)
            {
                right_pair_score = get_pair_score(right_half[right_id]);
            }

            // Compare scores (but if left half is exhausted, just add right half)
            if (left_pair_score >= right_pair_score && left_id < left_half_size)
            {
                tmp_pairs[main_id] = left_half[left_id];
                left_id += 1;
                if (left_pair_score == right_pair_score)
                {
                    main_id += 1;
                    tmp_pairs[main_id] = right_half[right_id];
                    right_id += 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tmp_pairs[main_id] = right_half[right_id];
                right_id += 1;
            }
            main_id += 1;
        }
        // Copy tmp_pairs back into pairs
        for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
        {
            pairs[i] = tmp_pairs[i];
        }
        return true;
    }
}

bool is_new_loser_on_top_of_new_winner(int new_winner, int new_loser)
{
    // Check if adding pair_to_add will create a loop in locked
    // 1. Get all candidates that beat new_winner
    int number_of_direct_stronger_candidates = 0;
    int direct_stronger_candidates[MAX - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        // Lock in the second index which is where candidate i is a loser
        if (locked[i][new_winner] == true)
        {
            if (i == new_loser)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                is_new_loser_on_top_of_new_winner(i, new_loser);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{

    // Then start filling it out
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        pair pair_to_add = pairs[i];
        if (!is_new_loser_on_top_of_new_winner(pair_to_add.winner, pair_to_add.loser))
        {
            // Add pair_to_add
            locked[pair_to_add.winner][pair_to_add.loser] = true;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        bool i_is_unbeaten = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
        {
            // If j has an edge over i, i is not a winner
            if (locked[j][i])
            {
                i_is_unbeaten = false;
            }
        }
        if (i_is_unbeaten)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i]);
            return;
        }
    }
    return;
}

Any suggestions?

Well the error is quite clear: You try to use a variable named main_id but it hasn't been declared. And please [edit] your question to show us a [mre].

Please add the code to the question. Your link is broken and the question should not rely on external resources anyway.

And as you yourself say, the error is in tideman_test.c, not in tideman.c. So seeing or looking at tideman.c wouldn't tell us anything.

Sorry about the broken link, I've replaced it with the explicit code. The error is indeed with tideman_test.c but the code referenced (eg while (main_id < left_half_size + right_half_size)) clearly is from tideman.c

As for main_id not being declared, I don't see where that would be the case. It's only used in merge_sort_pairs and is explicitly declared (and initialised): int main_id = 0;

A quick search indicates that this is an old problem (source). I agree with the comment saying that the problem is more likely in your code than in the CS50 internal code (which have worked fine for several thousands before you). As for the exact nature of the problem with your code, I can't tell.

I suggest you start over, with an empty main function and nothing more. Then add small pieces of code, one by one, and testing in between. Then when something goes wrong, it's easier to isolate it and try to figure out what the problem is and how to solve it.

main needs to remain untouched (it's pre-coded and mustn't be altered). That said, I've tried to narrow down the problem and it clearly is with merge_sort_pairs. I replaced its content with just a single return false; and check50 now compiles. I'll try to narrow it down further and post back with an update. Thanks

Ok so it turns out it was the variable main_id that broke things. I was also 99.9999% the issue was with my code but it seems to be a bug on CS50's after all. Any variable starting with main seems to cause this (I had tried to change it to main_id+xyz but still had the error). I changed it to tmp_id and it worked...

I suggest you write a proper answer about this issue. It has happened before, it happened to you, and it will happen for others in the future. If there's a proper answer it will be easier to find for the others in the future.

Yes that’s what I intend to do later today. Might try to ping CS50 support too.

I don't understand how naming a variable starting with main is breaking the code. Did you find the root of this bug?

I don’t know if that’s the actual reason but the error made no sense when looking at the code and the problem occurred whenever that variable was called main something. I don’t think we can troubleshoot this further without having access to tideman_test.c

@Will1v I made some searches and didn't find these tests to be public, unlike the libraries for C and Python et cetera. See: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/q/19511

Thanks @Harith. I’ve emailed an address I found on the CS50 page, will see if I get an answer. If not I might copy this post over to https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ (unless there’s a way to move this post over)

It seems all of this was cause by a variable starting with main (the original variable name was main_id which I changed to tmp_id). Eg:

main_id: tideman_test.c compilation fails
tmp_id: tideman_test.c compilation OK
main_tmp_id: tideman_test.c compilation fails
tmp_id_main: tideman_test.c compilation OK
main_blah: tideman_test.c compilation fails
blah_main_blah: tideman_test.c compilation OK

I haven't found a way to submit this as a bug to the CS50 team, but I did flag this post to them.
